# Is it possible to print out something in the browser debug console, so that when clicked on, will invoke a function?

Tags: javascript, developer-console

While debugging, I might have an element `el`, and I can print it out using `console.log(el)`.

There can be 50 or even 100 of them, while debugging.  Can I print out something in the debug console in Google Chrome, so that when I click on it, will make the element come into focus in the webpage?

I tried:

```
    let tmpLink = document.createElement("a");
    tmpLink.href = "#";   // now it is a link instead of anchor
    tmpLink.innerHTML = "Click Me";
    tmpLink.addEventListener("click", function() {
      el.focus();
    });
    console.log(tmpLink);
```

and the link is printed out in the debug console, except when I click on it, doesn't bring me to the element on page. Is there a way to do it?

One less desirable way is to do

```
window.focusArr = window.focusArr || [];
window.focusArr.push(el);
console.log(`Element ${window.focusArr.length - 1}`);
```

so I can just do in the console:

```
focusArr[21].focus()
```

But is there a way to make clicking on something work in the debug console?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't *exactly* what you're asking, but it may achieve the functionality you're looking for while debugging. In Chrome, if you log the actual element that you'd want to focus on, you can log an exact reference to the element, and then right click on it in the console and select "Scroll into view":

[image]

(For your code, you'd have to do `console.log(el)` so that the `el` that you're interested in can be right-clicked on and zoomed to)

Comment: ok, i will wait for an hour or two to see if I can have a "click on me and do anything" kind of solution... but this method works if it is just to focus on the element

Answer (score 1):

Just log the element itself.

```js
let e = document.getElementById('main');
console.log(e)
```

```html
<div id="main">
Hello
</div>
```

You can then right click on the element in the log message and choose "Scroll into view"

[image]

Comment: ok, i will wait for an hour or two to see if I can have a "click on me and do anything" kind of solution... but this method works if it is just to focus on the element